# JQuery UI Sortable Element not moving according to mouse

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery UI sortable. Everything is working fine except that when I drag an element to another element the element is not moving according to mouse pointer. That is pointer goes first and when the pointer stops then the element comes to the pointer position. Am I doing something wrong or is there a setting to do this?

My code is following:

```
jQuery( "#test1" ).sortable({
        start:function(event, ui) {
          $("#test2").css('background-color','#ebf2f9');
          $("#test2").css('border','2px dashed #3b73af');

          $("#test3").css('background-color','#ebf2f9');
          $("#test3").css('border','2px dashed #3b73af');
        },
        over: function(event, ui) {
          var parent_id = ui.item.parent().attr('id');
          if(parent_id != "test1") {
            $("#test1").css('background-color','#f3f9f4');
            $("#test1").css('border','2px dashed #14892c');
          }
        },
        deactivate:function(event, ui) {
          $("#test1").css('background-color','white');
          $("#test1").css('border','none');
        },
        out:function(event, ui) {
          var parent_id = ui.item.parent().attr('id');
          if(parent_id != "test1") {
            $("#test1").css('background-color','#ebf2f9');
            $("#test1").css('border','2px dashed #3b73af');
          }
        },
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
          var accepted = $("#test1").sortable('toArray');
          var pending = $("#test2").sortable('toArray');
          var all = $("#test3").sortable('toArray');
          console.log(ui.item.html());
          sendAjaxRequest(all,accepted,pending);
        },
        receive:function( event, ui ) {
          var item_id = ui.item.attr('id');
          var sender_id = ui.sender.attr('id');
          //Updating Counter
          updateCounters(sender_id,'test1_count_display');
          var html = ui.item.html();
          ui.item.children('.post-icons').html('');
        },
        connectWith: ".sortable-scroll-holder"
      }).disableSelection();
    });
```

And I have total three sortable lists and all of them are connected to each other.

This is the HTML of one of the elements:

```
<ul id="test1" class="connectedSortable1" style="min-height: 900px; float: left; width: 20%; margin: 0 5%; padding: 100px 0 0; list-style: none;">
        <li id="aleem1" style="background-color: #000; color: #fff; padding: 10px; margin: 0 0 10px;">
            <span class="name" style="display: none !important;" data-search-term="additonal additonal">additonal additonal</span>
            <span class="title" style="display: none !important;" data-search-term="Walt Disney World">Walt Disney World</span>
            <span class="company" style="display: none !important;" data-search-term="redsignal greensignal">redsignal greensignal</span>
            <span class="email" style="display: none !important;" data-search-term="kashaf@asdasd.com">kashaf@asdasd.com</span>
            <span class="network_group" style="display: none !important;" data-search-term=""></span>
            <span class="department" style="display: none !important;" data-search-term="ddfdf">ddfdf</span>
            <div class="img">               <img src="http://192.168.1.191:8000/images/speakers/no-img.jpg" alt="" width="38">
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <h6>additonal attendee</h6>
                <div class="text-cs">
                    <p>                   Walt Disney World at redsignal greensignal
                    </p>
                    <p>Department ddfdf</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="post-icons"></ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please attach your html in the question.

Comment: HTML attached to the question. But it is one of the element there can be hundreds of them.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have too much code being fired per step of the drag. Look at what you execute per step and reduce or remove it. Usual jquery dom performance aspects would be appropriate, such as caching elements to avoid repeating selections etc.

Comment: This did not work for me. Any other thing. I have tried these things.

Comment: Post a JSFiddle and I will have a look.

Comment: Thankyou very much the problem is solved. It was my css that was messing up. There was a transition property of css that was conflicting with it.

Comment: Great news, another dead bug. Could you accept my answer if it helped, or upvote me if I was a little useful. Thanks.